# bash for loop with error when detecting non 200 response from curl

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl, while-loop

I got a bash script which reads URLs from different .txt files (ven Array defines the txt files) and I curl them and if the Response Code is not 200 it writes an error in error.txt

Sadly it always does it at the end, even if there is no error in any of the links, any idea why?

```
for i in "${ven[@]}"; do
        while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
                        IP=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null $line?upstream=$1)
                                if [ $IP != 200 ]
                                then
                                counter=$((counter + 1))
                                echo $(date +"%d.%m.%y %T") : $line >> error.txt
                                fi
        done < $i
done
```

Comment: A bogus last entry in your `ven` array?

Comment: ven=("1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt" "4.txt") - looks fine to me - am I missing smth?

Comment: It was a bogus in one of the textfiles :/ one line i oversaw in the 2.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has some quoting issues, although the main issue is the inconsistent use of test expression brackets (double vs. single) and how you are checking for the number.

```
if [[ "$IP" -ne 200 ]]
```

`-ne` means "not equal", and since you've already used double brackets stay consistent.

The other stuff is more preventative in the way you quote the variables:

```
for i in "${ven[@]}"; do
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        IP=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null "$line?upstream=$1")
        if [[ "$IP" -ne 200 ]]; then
            counter=$((counter + 1))
            echo "$(date +'%d.%m.%y %T')" : "$line" >> error.txt
        fi
    done < "$i"
done
```

> NOTE: If a site is redirecting ( 301 ) then it will show an error — something to maybe consider.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue, but thank you for pointing that out. I haven´t done to much with bash yet. I will get an editor to point out the formatting stuff. 301 redirects should also throw an error, since there URLs should not be redirected - but thanks.

Comment: The script worked fine after making the changes; if you are missing code in your question you should add it since it's not reproducible here. (eg. `counter=$((counter + 1))` is useless)...

Comment: Found the mistake, there was an emtpy line in one of the txt files. thanks.I use the counter later to log the number (echo -e 'Curl Requests had' $counter 'Errors' >> error.txt)